# YAML Anchor/Alias Error: while parsing a block mapping...did not find expected key

Tags: yaml

I have the following YAML file with an anchor and an alias for a structure that defines a configuration and has a "child" structure that extends the parent with one more attribute:

```
Thing1: &asdf
  setting: thingy
Extension:
  *asdf
  another: wow
```

It seems like this alias would be at the right level, but apparently indentation is a problem here.  The YAML extension in VSCode provides this hint:

`All mapping items must start at the same columnYAML`

I've tried changing the location of the alias:

```
Thing1: &asdf
  setting: thingy
Extension: *asdf
  another: wow
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution on this blog:

https://spacelift.io/blog/yaml

See the "YAML Overrides" section - the override `<<:` allows for the alias to be bumped to the left one level.

```
Thing1: &asdf
  setting: thingy
Extension:
  <<: *asdf
  another: wow
```